# removing multiple pipes from a list

Tags: python, list

so i have some data i have been trying to clean up, its a list and it looks like this

> a = [\nlondon\n\n18\n\n20\n\n30\n\n\n\n\njapan\n\n6\n\n80\n\n2\n\n\n\n\nSpain]

i have tried to clean it up by doing this

```
a.replace("\n", "|")
```

the output turn out like this :

> [london||18||20||30||||japan||6||80||2|||Spain]

if i do this:

```
a.replace("\n","")
```

i get this:

> [london,"", "", 18,"","",20"","",30,"","","",""japan,"",""6,"","",80,"","",2"","","","",Spain]

can anyone explain why i am having multiple pipes, spaces and whats the best way to clean the data.

Comment: Is `a` a list with one string, or just a string? Also, you output in no way matches the commands you are using, e.g. `replace` will not insert those `,` into the string, or split the list, and the number of `\n` does not match the number of `|` after the first replace.

Comment: i just gave a clue of what i was trying to achieve, i couldn't necessarily re-type the whole data, and it was based specifically on what i needed help with.

Comment: No one asked you to "re-type the whole data", but you can expect to get better help if the examples in your question are somewhat consistent and show what you really want to achieve (e.g., what does "clean the data" mean), so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Thanks anyway. sorry if i wasn't clear enough. i think i got the needed help already....cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and got this:

```py
a = ['\nlondon\n\n18\n\n20\n\n30\n\n\n\n\njapan\n\n6\n\n80\n\n2\n\n\n\n\nSpain']

print(a[0].replace("\n", ""))
```

Output:

```py
london182030japan6802Spain
```

Could you please clarify the exact input and the expected output? it does not seem correct yet and I have taken some liberties.

If your input was a string you can use `split()`:

```py
a = '\nlondon\n\n18\n\n20\n\n30\n\n\n\n\njapan\n\n6\n\n80\n\n2\n\n\n\n\nSpain'
print(a.split())
```

Output:

```py
['london', '18', '20', '30', 'japan', '6', '80', '2', 'Spain']
```

Comment: thanks your solution worked. is there a way i can cycle through the list and match the countries with each numbers e.g "London 18 20 30", "Japan 6 80 2" how can i achieve that?

Comment: Yes definitely, the string method `isnumeric()` will return true for numbers represented in string format. So I would make an  empty list in a list `my_new_ls = [[]]` - then do a for loop on your data list: `for i in my_list:` then I would check if it was numeric `if i.isnumeric():` the if true, `my_new_arr[-1].append(i)` my `else:` would be `my_new_arr.append(i)`

Comment: I cant thank you enough, your logic is outstanding. but i noticed something further. isnumeric doesn't work for any value that has a comma separated values like this : 10,200. is there any work around for values like that?

Comment: Not a worry, if you had the string `my_string = '10, 200'` I would use `all()` like this `val = [i.isnumeric() for i in my_string.split(',')]` - So you split it into a list `['10', '20']` then check if all of them are numeric and it will pass `True` if that is the case

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is:

```
s = '\nlondon\n\n18\n\n20\n\n30\n\n\n\n\njapan\n\n6\n\n80\n\n2\n\n\n\n\nSpain'
```

The issue is that there are multiple `'\n'` in-between data, therefore just replacing each `'\n'` with another character (say `'|'`) will give you as many of the new characters as there were `'\n'`.

The simplest approach is to use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the non-blank data:

```
l = list(s.split())
print(l)
# ['london', '18', '20', '30', 'japan', '6', '80', '2', 'Spain']
```

or, combine it with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), if you want to have it separated by `'|'`:

```
t = '|'.join(s.split())
print(t)
# london|18|20|30|japan|6|80|2|Spain
```